# How to avoid connecting all the points of a function graph with Plotly

Tags: f#, plotly

In a program that revolves around maths, I find myself using Plotly.NET (F#) to display user-defined functions. This works quite well, but there are cases where a function has discontinuities or even chunks defined over certain regions. For example, for the function f(x) defined by 0 if x <= 0 and 10 elsewhere, the expected graph (I used Wolfram Alpha here) is:

[image: The expected graphe]

With Plotly and the code below,

```
let fn x = if x <= 0.0 then 0.0 else 10.0

let xs = [ -10.0 .. 0.1 .. 10.0 ]
let ys = Seq.map fn xs

Chart.Line(xs, ys, UseDefaults = false)
|> Chart.withTitle @"$f(x)$"
|> Chart.savePNG("example")
```

I get this graph:

[image: My graphe]

As you can see, Plotly connects two points that shouldn't be connected (and I don't blame it, that's how the lib works). I wonder then how to avoid this kind of behaviour, which often happens with piecewise defined functions.

If possible, I would like a solution that is general enough to be applied to all functions / graphs, as my program does not encode functions in advance, the user enters them. The research I've done doesn't lead me anywhere, unfortunately, and the documentation doesn't show an example for what I want.

PS: also, you may have noticed, Plotly doesn't display the LaTex in the exported image, according to my research this is a known issue with Python, but if you know how to solve this with the .NET version of the lib, I'm also interested!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way for Plotly to know that the function is discontinuous. Note that the vertical portion of your chart isn't truly vertical, because `x` jumps from `0.0` to `0.1`.

However, you can still achieve the effect you're looking for by creating a separate chart for each piece of the function, and then combining them:

```ml
let color = Color.fromString "Blue"

let xsA = [ -10.0 .. 0.0 ]
let ysA = xsA |> Seq.map (fun _ -> 0.0)
let chartA = Chart.Line(xsA, ysA, LineColor = color)

let xsB = [ 0.0 .. 10.0 ]
let ysB = xsB |> Seq.map (fun _ -> 10.0)
let chartB = Chart.Line(xsB, ysB, LineColor = color)

[ chartA; chartB ]
    |> Chart.combine
    |> Chart.withLegend false
    |> Chart.show
```

Note that there are actually two distinct points for `x = 0` in the combined chart, so it's technically not a function. (Perhaps there's some way to show that the top piece is open, while the bottom piece is closed in Plotly, but I don't know how.) Result is:

[image]

Comment: This is an ingenious solution, I will try to apply it to my program, thank you :)